# What is the correct use of namespaces is a javascript application?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, javascript-objects

I recently started a new project. And in order to improve my JavaScript skills I decided to write my code using namespaces (object based).

I decided to use this pattern only because I found it easy (for my level) and clear to read and write.

So is the following a good way to write an app?

```
var APP = APP || {};
APP.myProperty = {
    firstMethod: function(){
        // magic happens here...
    },
    secondMethod: function(){
        // more magic...
    }
}
APP.myProperty.myFirstMethod();
APP.myProperty.mySecondMethod();
```

I am also interested in using function expressions, like so:

```
var myModule = (function () {
    var privateMethod = function () {
        console.log('A private method');
    },
    someMethod = function () {
        console.log('A public method');
    },
    anotherMethod = function () {
        console.log('Another public method');
    };

    return {
        someMethod: someMethod,
        anotherMethod: anotherMethod
    };
}());
```

I would appreciate your feedback very much! Thanks

Comment: You should probably use what you're most comfortable with, but that's already a pretty good start! If you want to take modularization further (beware it's probably now a beginner's level), you could write your code in different files and use tools like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to compile everything down to a single file.

Comment: Just a style suggestion.  I generally don't use the "var ..., ..., ..." format with function declarations as that sends off alarm bells for function definitions (my brain thinks you are putting them in global scope implicitly).  I would suggest not doing it for function definitions just because you will have a bit of logic between the start and end of the declaration so could impact readability.  Purely a style choice though

Comment: Got it Aliester. No var stripping. Thanks